# Better way of displaying grouped periodic data

Tags: usability, layout, reports

I am working on a report where I have to display hierarchical data in relation to some type. For cumulative data over some period I have a table as presented in image below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxaDO.jpg):

[image: Cumulative]

The task is to display same data but periodically, so user can compare changes over time. My idea is to use table as presented in second chart:

[image]

This seems to be a large table - do you think there is a better way to display the data?

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: I think the way you have it in your second table would make it difficult to compare a single body type... New Estate vs Used Estates... What about a series of your table 1 with up/down indicators next to the values.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which informations are the most valuable but you already can simplify the table by using more than a row by cell.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNOY1B.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This recommendation seems valid and it simplifes the visual layout making it a lot easier to scan. It isn't clear that it is an advantage to group estate > age as is done here or age > estate like is done in the poster's. If you prefer the latter, I would eliminate the used label and treat each of the date periods as peers. That would simplify the table which is the main problem I'm having.